# Subquery with last test

Tags: sql, subquery

Please could anyone help me with this
Environment: MS Access 2010, Windows 7 
I would like to connect two queries
1) active persons in a specific program (her 9)
2) with their last test

**add 1)**

```
SELECT per.perNachname,
       per.perMitgliedsnummer,
       prm.prmID,
       tei.teiangIDRef,
       tei.teiperIDRef,
       prm.prmpdaIDRef,
       prm.prmdegIDRef
FROM ( tblPersonen AS per
       RIGHT JOIN tblTeilnahmen AS tei 
       ON 
       (per.perMitgliedsnummer=tei.teiperIDRef 
        AND  tei.teiangIDRef = 9)
      )
       LEFT JOIN 
       tblPromotionTest  AS prm
       ON 
       prm.prmperIDRef=per.perMitgliedsnummer
```

This works but I see to much rows instead of this I would like to see for every person only the row with the last test or nothing on the right side if this person hasn’t passed any test. >>> the idea is something like tblPERSON LEFT JOIN tblTEST <<<

**add 2)**

```
SELECT p.prmperIDRef,
       p.prmID,
       p.prmpdaIDRef,
       p.prmdegIDRef
FROM tblPromotionTest AS p 
     LEFT JOIN tblPromotionTest AS p2 
     ON (p.prmID < p2.prmID) 
     AND (p.prmperIDRef=p2.prmperIDRef)
     WHERE p2.prmperIDRef Is Null
```

Thanks in advance for your support 
kind regards Bernhard

i found following circumvention:

```
SELECT per.perNachname, per.perVorname, per.perMitgliedsnummer, prm.prmID, prm.prmpdaIDRef, prm.prmdegIDRef

FROM tblPersonen AS per LEFT JOIN tblPromotionTest AS prm ON per.perMitgliedsnummer = prm.prmperIDRef

WHERE prm.prmID IN (
SELECT p.prmID
FROM tblPromotionTest AS p LEFT JOIN tblPromotionTest AS p2 ON (p.prmID < p2.prmID) AND (p.prmperIDRef=p2.prmperIDRef)
WHERE p2.prmperIDRef Is Null)

AND per.perMitgliedsnummer IN 

(
SELECT tei.teiperIDRef
FROM tblPersonen AS per INNER JOIN tblTeilnahmen AS tei ON per.perMitgliedsnummer = tei.teiperIDRef
WHERE (((tei.teiangIDRef)=9))
)

UNION SELECT per.perNachname, per.perVorname, per.perMitgliedsnummer,  prm.prmID, prm.prmpdaIDRef, prm.prmdegIDRef
FROM tblPersonen AS per LEFT JOIN tblPromotionTest AS prm ON per.perMitgliedsnummer = prm.prmperIDRef
WHERE prm.prmID Is Null and per.perMitgliedsnummer IN (SELECT tei.teiperIDRef
FROM tblTeilnahmen as tei
WHERE tei.teiangIDRef=9);
```

Comment: I found no way to uns a where statement only for one specific join.

Comment: My cirumvention is the using of an UNION statement: